# how to save data from multiple tabs on single save in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to create a UI with multiple tabbs using bootstrapp tab . I need to be able to do the following

View all the tab data by navigating between tabs

A common save for all the tab data should render all the Tabs and user should be able to save/edit data for all the elements by navigating between Tabs randomly.

I have achieved the tabs like below

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <ul id="datatabs" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#details" id="TabDetailsLink">Personal Details</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" id="Tab2Link">tab2</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3" id="Ttab2Link">tab3</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4" id="Tab4Link">tab4</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab5" id="Tab5Link">tab5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="DataView" class="tab-content"> 
            <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade">
                <br />
                //here I have my controls
            </div>
            <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
                <br />
            </div>
            <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
                <br />
            </div>   
        </div>
```

Detail entity:

```
    public class Detail : XXXBaseEntity
    {
        public int tab1ID { get; set; }
        public string tab1name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Tab2> StudentStaffs { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tab3> tab3Data { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tab4> Emails { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tab5> Tab5 { get; set; }
    }
```

Detail view Model

```
 public class DetailVM
    {
        public Detail Details{ get; set; }

    }
```

Could someone tell me how to achieve this with the best practice in ASP.NET MVC 4?User should be able to save the Forms data (from all the tabs) to the database(diffent tables) in one button click.

Comment: You've not said how you load the data into the tabs, eg on load or via ajax.   Simplest solution is to have a view model with your existing models as properties, then POST that.

Comment: Edited model and view model

Comment: @jubi, what have you tried so far and what problems are you encountering with that approach?

Comment: Honestly , i am stucked in how i can implement this.I have designed a view based on my view model. now how can i achieve save

Comment: I am loading each partial view from the jquery. Now i am wondering how i can save all the tab s data in one save.Details need to be saved in different tables.